# cordova-icon utility throws error "spawn convert ENOENT"

Tags: android, ios, cordova, icons

I'm developing an Android/iOS Cordova app. Given the sheer number of icons I should manually create and set into the config.xml, I decided to user this nice tool [cordova-icon](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon). It isn't a Cordova plugin, it's just an npm tool which takes your icon.png 1024x1024 and creates all the icon set for Android and iOS, plus it sets the appropriate configuration inside the config.xml file.

Unfortunately I get this error:

[image]

And I have no idea why. The icon.png is found, the config.xml is found. Platforms Android and iOS are also found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the error, I didn't have the `image-magick` library installed.

I simply had to install it...

> $ brew install image-magick

... and then it worked

Comment: for me (iOS) it was `imagemagick` without the hyphen

Answer (score 2):

For one reason or another, that plugin stopped working for me, so I've since switched to [app-icon](https://github.com/dwmkerr/app-icon) and it has worked like a charm!